# Which web3 version is correct?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I checked my web3 version in two way, and those two show different web3 version.

This is one

```
$ npm ls web3
frontend@0.1.0 /Users/__/Desktop/MyApps/eth_todo_react/frontend
└── web3@1.0.0-beta.52
```

This is two

```
var version = web3.version.api;
undefined
version
"0.20.3"
```

Which one is correct web3 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct or wrong.
`1.0.0-x` is still in beta.
On the other hand `0.2x.x` is more stable but it lacks some features such as `Promises`, `WebSockets`(even though 1.0.0 isn't doing that great at `websockets` at some point)

After all you can't go wrong with either one. Just refer to the corrects docs:
Docs for [web3.js `0.2x.x`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)
Docs for [web3.js `1.0.x-x`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

All Are correct but

```
Web3 0.2x.x
```

Versions are Stable & Use full in all frame works.